# How to update an array of struct?

Tags: solidity, remix

this is my code:

```
struct Entity{
    address _address;
    uint data;
}

   Entity[] entityArray;

function addEntityArray(uint _data)  public returns(uint){
    entityArray.push(Entity((msg.sender), _data));
    return entityArray[(entityArray.length) - 1].data;
}
```

to update a struct in this array at any point in time, i will need to keep track of the address and the index of it using MAPPING right? or i have to loop everytime which is costly in gas...
how to tackle this issue in the best way possible?

Comment: are you sure you need an array? why not a mapping from address -> data?

Comment: I did use the structure you suggested, but for another use case, I need an array to loop through and do some work // or return an array of those objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way to update a single instance of the array is for every address that invokes `addEntityArray()` to store the index of the struct.

The mapping would look like this:

```
mapping(address => uint) public addressesEntityIndex;
```

**Note:** it is better to store the index to the struct, not a whole struct because it is cheaper.

The updated function would look like this:

```
function addEntityArray(uint _data)  public returns(uint){
    Entity storage newEntity = Entity(msg.sender, _data);
    uint entityIndex = entityArray.length;
    entityArray.push(newEntity);
    addressesEntityIndex[msg.sender] = entityIndex;
    return entityArray[entityIndex].data;
}
```

**Note:** I slightly modified your function's design, it will cost a bit more gas but it is more human-readable.

And finally, you define a function that will update:

```
function updateEntityArray(uint _data) public {
    uint addressEntityIndex = addressesEntityIndex[msg.sender];
    entityArray[addressEntityIndex].data = _data
}
```

Comment: looks good, but when u declared "newEntity" why did u put it in storage? if you make it 

  Entity memory newEntity = Entity(msg.sender, _data);

it would be much cheaper

Comment: Yes, but if you declared it in `memory` the moment you addit to the `entityArray` (`entityArray.push(newEntity);`) it will be added in the storage and now you have it once in `memory` and once in `storage` where as if you declared directly to `storage` you omit the `memory` declaration.

Comment: ohhh, very true! i forgot about the refference and copy between storage and memory.
thanks alot for the answer!

Comment: you are welcome. dont forget to upvote :)

Comment: i did but dont have enough reps :D once i do it'll appear

Comment: @HristoTodorov You mentioned that it's more expensive. Why is that?

Comment: What happens when the updateEntityArray method is called with an address that is not in the addressesEntityIndex? Wouldn't that return `0` and therefor update the wrong item in the array?

Comment: Yes you are correct. This can be bypassed if shift all of the recors by one which is easily done if instead of initialising the array as empty to have one stored item in it.

Comment: It is cheaper because if you want only the index you can get rid of the address which take bock space which lead to bigger cost